# Bitwise flag issue

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitflags

I have a series of bit flags that order something like `{none=0x00, puppies=0x01, kittens=0x02, cute=0x04, funny=0x08, scary=0x10}` and so forth.

Whenever a user does a search, I just `|=` each of the flags that they wish, e.g. if a user wants something of cute kittens, I would just `search |= cute` and `search |= kittens`.

Yet, when I carry out the search operation, by looping through and checking all my items where that item's `(flag & search) != 0`, it instead returns items that have cute attributes OR kittens. How can I change this so it returns cute attributes AND kittens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've masked out irrelevant flags with your `(flag & search)` expression. Now you just have to ensure that *all* requested flags are present. So, instead of doing `(flag & search) != 0`, do `(flag & search) == search`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That made some sense now!

Answer (score 1):

if((flags&cute) && (flags&kittens))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping and checking each flag one at a time, check the search against all the flags combined:

```
((flag1 | flag2 | flag3) & search) == search
```